# How to connect LIS3DHTR accelerometer pins?

Tags: sensor, accelerometer, pinout

I want use LIS3DHTR in one of my projects. I have problem with some pins of this sensor.

ADC pins: I want to connect some sensors with wire to jumper, is it OK? Datasheet said we can connect ADC pins to Vdd, GND or leave float (if we don't want use them). Should I pull-up or pull-down them or using jumper? What is best solution?

SDO/SA0 pin: I want to use I2C for communication with MCU,
for change I2C address is this jumper and pull-up OK? Is there any problem for this pin?

RES pin: What is this pin? Datasheet said to connect RES pin to GND.

INT pins: Interrupt pins are connect to MCU directly or need anything?

Vdd_IO pin: Datasheet said to connect some caps (10 μF and 100 nF) between Vdd and GND, connect 2 extra caps for Vdd_IO make problem or no? Is it good for circuit or no?

[image: LIS3DHTR Accelerometer circuit schematic]

Comment: Welcome! I don't see any way to change the I2C address. You need to pull CS high to enable I2C communication. RES most probably stands for reset.

Comment: Have you tried finding the answers to your questions in the [datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/lis3dh-1849589.pdf)?

Comment: Yes I try but there isn't complete answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source: [LIS3DHTR datasheet](https://www.mouser.ch/datasheet/2/389/lis3dh-1849589.pdf)

> ADC pins: I want to connect some sensors with wire to jumper, is it OK? Datasheet said we can connect ADC pins to Vdd, GND or leave float (if we don't want use them). Should I pull-up or pull-down them or using jumper? What is best solution?

As you already noted, the datasheet states that unused ADC inputs can be connected to Vdd, GND, or be left floating. It's really up to you what's best, all three options are equally valid.

I personally would leave them floating with an option to connect a signal, just in case some requirements change at a later stage. I like to have options.

> SDO/SA0 pin: I want to use I2C for communication with MCU, for change I2C address is this jumper and pull-up OK? Is there any problem for this pin?

`SDO/SA0` already has an internal pull-up, which is enabled by default. Using the internal pull-up, and adding an external jumper to GND would suffice. But an additional external 10 kΩ pull-up certainly wouldn't pose a problem.

> RES pin: What is this pin? Datasheet said to connect RES pin to GND.

The datasheet doesn't say what `RES` is. I'm assuming it's a 'reserved' pin. But in the end it doesn't really matter. According to the datasheet you should connect it to GND, and that's all you really need to know.

> INT pins: Interrupt pins are connect to MCU directly or need anything?

The interrupt pins are push-pull (by default), so you can directly connect them to the MCU without external components.

> Vdd_IO pin: Datasheet said to connect some caps (10 uF and 100 nF) between Vdd and GND, connect 2 extra caps for Vdd_IO make problem or no? Is it good for circuit or no?

The datasheet isn't very clear when it comes to `Vdd_IO`. They're only specifying that you need to add decoupling capacitors (100 nF ceramic, 10 μF aluminum) to the `Vdd` pin. But it couldn't hurt to connect an additional 100 nF to `Vdd_IO`.

ST has an evaluation board: [STEVAL-MKI105V1](https://www.st.com/resource/en/data_brief/steval-mki105v1.pdf)

Here you can see that they're doing exactly that:

- Vdd: 10 μF & 100 nF
- Vdd_IO: 100 nF

[image]

Note: All three caps are ceramic. The 10 μF isn't aluminum like specified.

[image]